# How to sample 75 percent of rows from a dtm?

Tags: r, sample, tm

How I can sample a dtm? I trying a lot of code but return me the same error

> Error in dtm[splitter, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

This is the code:

```
n <- dtm$nrow
splitter <- sample(1:n, round(n * 0.75))
train_set <- dtm[splitter, ]
valid_set <- dtm[-splitter, ]
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. You can try ```n <- nrow(dtm)```

Comment: In principle, your code should work if dtm is a DocumentTermMatrix / sparse matrix, so can you show how you generate `dtm`  or at least the output of `str(dtm)` please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the quanteda package for this. See example below:

Created data example based on the crude data set from tm:

```
library(tm)

data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
crude <- tm_map(crude, stemDocument)

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude)


library(quanteda)

# Transform your dtm into a dfm for quanteda
my_dfm <- as.dfm(dtm)

# number of documents    
ndocs(my_dfm)
[1] 20

set.seed(4242)

# create training
train_set <- dfm_sample(my_dfm, 
                        size = round(ndoc(my_dfm) * 0.75),  # set sample size
                        margin = "documents")

# create test set by select the documents that do not match the documents in the training set.
test_set <- dfm_subset(my_dfm, !docnames(my_dfm) %in% docnames(train_set))

# number of documents in train
ndoc(train_set)
[1] 15

# number of documents in test
ndoc(test_set)
[1] 5
```

Afterwards you can use the quanteda function `convert` to convert your train and test sets to be used with topicmodels, lda, lsa, etc. See `?convert` for more info.

Comment: The code in the OP works on your `dtm`, this suggests that there is something else going on with their `dtm` object

Answer (score 0):

Try using caret package:

```
library(caret)
#help(package="caret")

index <- createDataPartition(sample, times = 1, p=0.75, list = FALSE)
train <- news.raw[index,]
test  <- news.raw[-index,]
```

Hope this helps.!